# jQuery click link find div with matching id scrollTo

Tags: jquery, hyperlink, filter, scrollto

I am creating a page. I have the following HTML:

```
        <ul id="nav">
            <li><a href="#section1">Link</a></li>
            <li><a href="#section2">Link</a></li>
            <li><a href="#section3">Link</a></li>
            <li><a href="#section4">Link</a></li>
            <li><a href="#section5">Link</a></li>
            <li><a href="#section6">Link</a></li>
        </ul>

        <div class="section">
            <p>Content</p>
        </div>

        <div class="section" id="section1">
            <p>Content</p>
        </div>

        <div class="section">
            <p>Content</p>
        </div>

        <div class="section" id="section2">
            <p>Content</p>
        </div>

        <div class="section">
            <p>Content</p>
        </div>

        <div class="section" id="section3">
            <p>Content</p>
        </div>

        <div class="section">
            <p>Content</p>
        </div>

        <div class="section" id="section4">
            <p>Content</p>
        </div>

        <div class="section">
            <p>Content</p>
        </div>

        <div class="section" id="section5">
            <p>Content</p>
        </div>

        <div class="section">
            <p>Content</p>
        </div>

        <div class="section" id="section6">
            <p>Content</p>
        </div>
```

What I would like to achieve is when a link is clicked. Use jQuery to find a div with the same id as the links href and then scroll the page to that div. Can anyone point me in the right direction? The bit I am struggling with is how to match the id to the href.

Many thanks.

Comment: maybe you should use jquery tabs http://jqueryui.com/demos/tabs/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could achieve this by this way:

```
$('#nav li a').click(function(){
    //Scroll to targetID offsetTop.. or using the scrollTo plugin, scrolling to $($(this).attr('href'))
})
```

[scrollTo plugin](http://demos.flesler.com/jquery/scrollTo/)

Comment: thanks for the advice. If I was using this plugin (looks great BTW) where would I put the ref to the hash in the .scrollTo call?

Comment: the ref to the hash (#target), wrapped within $, is the jQuery target element, so if you call scrollTo passing that target element, it should work :) .. Btw I don't know if the plugin is updated and is working with latest jQuery version. You'd have to check :)

Answer (score 3):

Add a click event to each of the anchor tags.  The use the [attr](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) function to get the href of the selected element.

I've then used the animate function to scroll to this element.

```
$(function(){
    $('#nav li a').click(function(){
        var divID = $(this).attr('href');
        $('html,body').animate({
            scrollTop: $(divID).offset().top 
        }, {
            duration: 'slow', 
            easing: 'swing'
        }); 
    }); 
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this :

```
$('#nav a').click(function(){
  $($(this).attr('href')).whatyouwant();
});
```